# How to use the splat parameter in Durandal router?

Tags: durandal

The article I am looking at is [Durandal Router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Router.html).

Under `mapAuto`, it says we can pass splat parameter in the url `#/customers/1`. and the `activate` function in the viewmodel will be able to retrieve the parameter array.

I built a route here

```
router.mapRoute('view/:id', moduleId, 'Customer Details', false);
```

But how can I obtain the `id` in the `activate` function? There is no example on the doc page. Please help us out. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your activate function a single parameter, perhaps named something like "data".

The id that was passed into the url will then be available within the activate function as "data.id".

```
var activate = function(data) {
    alert(data.id);
};
```

Comment: Now in Durandal 2, each url fragment gets its own argument (i.e. key is no longer provided, just the value), any query string parameters are contained in a last argument. See "Update Modules" at http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide/

Comment: Durandal2 Conversion Guide is at http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Conversion-Guide.html